# My golang program profiling using pprof shows memory increasing at json (* decodeState) objectInterface in std/json package

Tags: go, memory-leaks, unmarshalling

I have a golang program that uses unmarshall from std "encoding/json" package keeps increasing in size (memory leak). A diagram of memory profile using pprof shows memory increasing at json (* decodeState) objectInterface. I want to understand how and why it could be happening to fix the issue.

I have tried several things at upper level like release of returned value to avoid the leak, but with no success.

```
func (j JSONEncoding) From(b []byte, msg interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &msg)
    return msg, err
}
```

pprof top5 shows this call, and the details below;

```
4096.89kB 24.43% 24.43%  4096.89kB 24.43%  encoding/json.(*decodeState).objectInterface

(pprof) list objectInterface
Total: 20.65MB
ROUTINE ======================== encoding/json.(*decodeState).objectInterface in /usr/local/go/src/encoding/json/decode.go
       6MB     7.50MB (flat, cum) 36.32% of Total
         .          .   1061:   return v
         .          .   1062:}
         .          .   1063:
         .          .   1064:// objectInterface is like object but returns map[string]interface{}.
         .          .   1065:func (d *decodeState) objectInterface() map[string]interface{} {
       3MB        3MB   1066:   m := make(map[string]interface{})
         .          .   1067:   for {
         .          .   1068:       // Read opening " of string key or closing }.
.
. deleted code
.
         .          .   1095:
         .          .   1096:       // Read value.
       3MB     4.50MB   1097:       m[key] = d.valueInterface()
```

using topN, and using visualization I can see this box increasing with time/processing.

This unmarshall is called in a loop but nothing is saved that could be a reason for the leak. I am not sure how and what of something to be done so that this leak is avoided.

**Update**: 
The memory leak was more of a memory accrual, in the code at some other place. While trying to write a minimum code that shows the problem, I was not able to reproduce, and had to dig all the code to find out that an internal library was using a map to cache and the cache cleaner was not working properly.

My problem was that pprof is giving info on who is allocating, but not where it is being kept. I think my question should have been, how can we find out which objects have references of what size. I know that one allocated reference could be in multiple places but such information would easily help in finding this kind of issue.

Comment: That profile shows where some allocations are made, but doesn’t provide any information about a leak

Comment: 1) Verify you actually have a problem, 2) Write an [MCVE]

Comment: Over time, these keep increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why don't you do something like this:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

```
func (a *Animal) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch strings.ToLower(s) {
    default:
        *a = Unknown
    case "gopher":
        *a = Gopher
    case "zebra":
        *a = Zebra
    }

    return nil
}
```

In other words, is your implementation preventing objects (like "err", for example) from being garbage collected?

Comment: This is part of a library code that is extensively reused by other programs and leak is not an issue in but one use of this lib. I have tried do things differently but it would be good to know what you think would cause prevention of garbage collection? Have even tried a drop in replacement of encoding/json but still see the issue.

Comment: Dude - you showed us some suspicious code ... I suggested why it might be suspicious ... and your only response appears to be "it's gotta be the GoLang library!"  Frankly, "json.Unmarshal" is the *LAST* thing I'd consider.  First: 1) Verify that you indeed HAVE a leak (maybe you're misinterpreting the stats), 2) Look at your usage (as I tried to suggest), 3) Write a standalone [MCVE] to try to reproduce the problem *INDEPENDENTLY*.  If you really have a problem, then 1) [MCVE] is your best bet, 2) worrying about json.Unmarshal is your last fallback.

Comment: I don't think I said that the leak is in library. Replacing std library did not fix the issue either.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for you to write an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)